# Set gitlab-ci variable conditional on another variable

Tags: regex, variables, gitlab, conditional-statements, gitlab-ci

A fairly common need is to set some variable values based on another variable value. I cannot find a way to do this in the "variables" section of a gitlab-ci.yml file.

I have a pipeline that builds a number of deployable images. What I want to do is choose the FQDNs of the set of virtual machines to which I want to deploy the built images, based on the deployment environment name defined in a Gitlab pipeline variable. It's a little more complex than that, but any kind of case statement, if/then/else or table lookup would satisfy the requirement.

How can gitlab-ci support this?

Comment: I tried this, which CI Lint found acceptable, but which did not produce the desired result:

    `TARGET: $( $DEPLOY_INTO_ENVIRONMENT == "CI" && "TEST" || "DEPLOY" )`

Comment: You don't have to use the `variables` section, that's only a convenience. You can always create your variables with shell scripts

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - I was thinking along exactly those lines.

Comment: The following works in the before_script:

`- export TARGET=$( [[ "$DEPLOY_INTO" == "CI" ]] && echo "TEST" || echo "PROD" )`

Comment: Unfortunately variables defined in this way cannot be referenced in "only:variables" clauses to select whether a job will run or not.

Comment: @ImmoHuneke you should post that as an answer. It's useful even two years later :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for this.

Since GitLab 13.10 (released 2021/03/22) you can do this with [`rules:variables:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesvariables)

```yaml
deploy:
  variables:
    ENV_NAME:
      description: The name of the environment in which to deploy the image
      value: "default"
      options: # populate UI drop-down in GitLab 15.7+
        - production
        - staging
  rules:
    - if: $ENV_NAME == "production"
      variables:
        TARGET_FQDN: "host.prod.exmaple.com"
    - if: $ENV_NAME == "staging"
      variables:
        TARGET_FQDN: "host.stage.example.com"
    - when: on_success # default case when above rules dont match
      variables:
        TARGET_FQDN: "localhost"
  script:
    - echo "deploying to $TARGET_FQDN"
```

Keep in mind `rules:variables:` can only operate on variables that exist at pipeline-creation time.

---

In GitLab 12.9 and later, you can use a script in a job (and optionally [dotenv reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv)) to set environment variables dynamically:

```yaml
set-variables:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$ENV_NAME" == "production" ]]; then
          TARGET_FQDN="foo"
      else
          TARGET_FQDN="bar"
      fi
      echo "TARGET_FQDN=${TARGET_FQDN}" > my.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: "my.env"

deploy:
  script:
    - deploying to "$TARGET_FQDN"
    # or just put the same logic in this job
```

Comment: Many thanks @sytech for your answer. I have moved on to another project long since, but I hope others find it useful.